# How to get the right correlation matrix for correlated binary data

Tags: r, correlation, simulation, binary-data

I am trying to generate correlated binary data in high dimensional in R using bindata lib given marginal probabilites and correlation matrix, but it give me always error

```
  Error in commonprob2sigma(commonprob, simulvals) : 
  Matrix commonprob not admissible.
```

Here is sample of code for only 10 variables:

```
marginal_probs =  c(9.795272e-01 , 9.331778e-01 , 6.764349e-01 , 9.884067e-02 ,9.522222e-05 , 3.499417e-03 , 2.380556e-05 , 9.826457e-01 , 9.628633e-01 ,8.874949e-01)


correlation_mat =

      [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]          [,5]          [,6]          [,7]          [,8]          [,9]       [,10]
 [1,]  1.0000000000  0.540258943  0.209031764  0.047879233 -6.750092e-02  0.0085672057  7.053822e-04  0.7840635867  0.6694665745  0.40604770
 [2,]  0.5402589429  1.000000000  0.386910326  0.088622750 -3.646798e-02 -0.0454879132  1.305637e-03  0.4929722619  0.6613106007  0.61159373
 [3,]  0.2090317635  0.386910326  1.000000000  0.229052428 -1.410984e-02 -0.0434598161 -7.054666e-03  0.1909793458  0.2831488805  0.49337866
 [4,]  0.0478792330  0.088622750  0.229052428  1.000000000 -3.231892e-03 -0.0101705338 -1.615888e-03  0.0434012259  0.0646190283  0.11766286
 [5,] -0.0675009217 -0.036467977 -0.014109837 -0.003231892  1.000000e+00 -0.0005782943 -4.761395e-05 -0.0734320072 -0.0496901947 -0.02740859
 [6,]  0.0085672057 -0.045487913 -0.043459816 -0.010170534 -5.782943e-04  1.0000000000  8.233515e-02  0.0078752345  0.0095061395 -0.03886223
 [7,]  0.0007053822  0.001305637 -0.007054666 -0.001615888 -4.761395e-05  0.0823351499  1.000000e+00  0.0006484086  0.0009582161  0.00173719
 [8,]  0.7840635867  0.492972262  0.190979346  0.043401226 -7.343201e-02  0.0078752345  6.484086e-04  1.0000000000  0.6766830516  0.37325133
 [9,]  0.6694665745  0.661310601  0.283148881  0.064619028 -4.969019e-02  0.0095061395  9.582161e-04  0.6766830516  1.0000000000  0.55158959
[10,]  0.4060477004  0.611593731  0.493378657  0.117662862 -2.740859e-02 -0.0388622278  1.737190e-03  0.3732513255  0.5515895878  1.00000000
```

This line:

```
     r <- rmvbin(10,margprob = marginal_probs, bincorr = correlation_mat)
```

Produces the following error:

```
Not all probabilities are between 0 and 1.
Error in Element ( 1 , 5 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 9.5222224867284e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 1 , 7 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 3 , 7 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 4 , 7 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 5 , 7 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 6 , 7 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 7 , 3 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 7 , 4 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 7 , 5 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 7 , 6 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 7 , 8 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 7 , 9 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 7 , 10 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 8 , 7 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 9 , 7 ): Admissible values are in [ 0 , 2.3805556216821e-05 ].
Error in Element ( 9 , 10 ): Admissible values are in [ 0.850358273621063 , 0.887494941319304 ].
Error in commonprob2sigma(commonprob, simulvals) : 
  Matrix commonprob not admissible.
```

I tried to use better inputs to be within range of each element with the following:

```
> corr_mat[1,5]=runif(1,min= 0,max = 9.5222224867284e-05)
> corr_mat[1,5]
[1] 8.459955e-05
> corr_mat[5,1]=8.459955e-05
```

and did the same for each element but for element (9,10) it give me the same error whatever value I use??

```
> r <- rmvbin(10,margprob = marginal_probs, bincorr = correlation_mat)
Error in Element ( 9 , 10 ): Admissible values are in [ 0.850358273621063 , 0.887494941319304 ].
Error in commonprob2sigma(commonprob, simulvals) : 
  Matrix commonprob not admissible.
```

Even after applying this:

```
> corr_mat[9,10]=0.887494941319304
> corr_mat[10,9]=0.887494941319304
> r <- rmvbin(10,margprob = probs[1:10], bincorr = corr_mat[1:10,1:10])
```

It still shows:

```
Error in Element ( 9 , 10 ): Admissible values are in [ 0.850358273621063 , 0.887494941319304 ].
Error in commonprob2sigma(commonprob, simulvals) : 
  Matrix commonprob not admissible.
```

And:

```
> corr_mat[9,10]=runif(1,min=0.850358273621063,max=0.887494941319304)
> corr_mat[9,10]
[1] 0.8520473
> corr_mat[10,9]=0.8520473
> r <- rmvbin(10,margprob = marginal_probs, bincorr = correlation_mat)
```

Shows:

```
Error in Element ( 9 , 10 ): Admissible values are in [ 0.850358273621063 , 0.887494941319304 ].
Error in commonprob2sigma(commonprob, simulvals) : 
  Matrix commonprob not admissible.
```

What's wrong in my code? How should I fix my correlation matrix?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Study `help("check.commonprob")`. Then look at `bincorr2commonprob(marginal_probs, correlation_mat)`. One obvious (but not the only) problem is that negative probabilities are calculated. The function obviously can't handle negative correlations.

Comment: I stopped reading at the point I looked at the upper $2\times 2$ quadrant of `correlation_mat`: because it obviously is not symmetric, it's not a correlation matrix.  GIGO.  Evidently some problem occurred in your computation of this matrix, but since you haven't explained how it was computed, there's no answerable question.

Comment: correlation_mat is a result of cor(Real_Binary_DS), I didn't make it up and even if I tried round(correlation_mat, digits = 8) not worked